# Marklogic datahub quick start app UI framework

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-dhf

What flex library/css does marklogic data-hub quick start application uses ? It seems they are using angular2-mdl in conjunction with some flex css/library. 
   I was wondering which flex library is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally I was using [Angular's Material2 library](https://github.com/angular/material2).

At some point I decided to switch to angular2-mdl but liked the scss files from Angular Material2 so I kept them around.